# History buckets not found in history.stellar.org

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, history

After update to stellar-core 10.0.0rc4 I got history issue. Synchronization is stuck.
Here is errors:

> 2018-09-14T14:08:36.090 GCUCN [default INFO] Loading last known ledger
>   2018-09-14T14:10:19.750 GCUCN [Ledger WARNING] Some buckets are missing in 'buckets'.
>   2018-09-14T14:10:19.750 GCUCN [Ledger WARNING] Attempting to recover from the history store.
>   2018-09-14T14:10:19.750 GCUCN [History INFO] Starting RepairMissingBucketsWork
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.844 GCUCN [Process WARNING] process 3160 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/bucket/7a/31/44/bucket-7a3144f8146a349e6d7f0f82c5a2b7299e64bea9515db17a9d31d6896e179181.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2806767400e7b59d/bucket-7a3144f8146a349e6d7f0f82c5a2b7299e64bea9515db17a9d31d6896e179181.xdr.gz.tmp
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.845 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/7a/31/44/bucket-7a3144f8146a349e6d7f0f82c5a2b7299e64bea9515db17a9d31d6896e179181.xdr.gz
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.845 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 2 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/7a/31/44/bucket-7a3144f8146a349e6d7f0f82c5a2b7299e64bea9515db17a9d31d6896e179181.xdr.gz
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.856 GCUCN [Process WARNING] process 3161 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2806767400e7b59d/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz.tmp
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.856 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz
>   2018-09-14T14:12:02.856 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #1/32 in 1 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz
>   2018-09-14T14:12:04.051 GCUCN [Process WARNING] process 3165 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz -o buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-2806767400e7b59d/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz.tmp
>   2018-09-14T14:12:04.051 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz
>   2018-09-14T14:12:04.051 GCUCN [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #2/32 in 1 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/ba/7f/a4/bucket-ba7fa4b182a76ac9ad4e2bf4071ce0c3858b05f4dc21ad91df21879c5bfaeccd.xdr.gz

"horizon_version": "0.14.0-unstable-044dc2a1669fb5305eedef5a4c6262b732e7d843",
  "core_version": "stellar-core 10.0.0rc4 (551d1bdb8d276e3d46de15a7f2d347fa96c2d593)"